# How to include globals.h in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, include, global

I need the correct syntax for

```
#include <globals.h>
```

to access the DvmGlobals struct.

How can I include Globals.h in my c++ file?
I tried several ways and always get the "unresolved inclusion" error.
I cannot find Globals.h on my NDK directory.

Comment: That header is part of [the Dalvik git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/), so it's not in the NDK because it's not something applications are supposed to use directly. Keep in mind that newer Android versions use ART instead of Dalvik, so what exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am trying to detect a debugger. I have seen the following code  if(gDvm.debuggerConnected || gDvm.debuggerActive) then debugger is on. Alternatively I can call java functions from my C++ , like ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0; - However the java function may not detect an NDK debugger. I just don't know - I will have to test.